# Would a .Locate be faster if u use an index?

Tags: delphi, indexing

Im using multiple locates on a large amount of data, locate does not require an index to function.
But would it be faster if I do have one?

Im using delphi.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981348/fastest-way-to-locate-record-in-tquery-resultset

Comment: Try and see. That all is very depending of virtue of data and the kind index and the implementation of DBMX engine. Also indices slow data modifications - too many indices is not necessarily good.

Comment: What DataSet class are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datasets are mostly abstract. It will depend on the underlying implementation what exactly happens when you call the locate method.

That being said, nearly every implementation that I know will use indexes (including DBF ones)